# Unable to redirect to another URL using action chain and post param

Tags: java, struts2, actionresult

Trying to redirect to external URL with post parameter.

My code is below:

```xml
 <action name="testit" class="TestAction" method="test">
            <result name = "success" type = "chain">
                <param name="location">${at.url}</param>
                <param name="login">${at.login}</param>
                <param name="pass">${at.pass}</param>
            </result>
</action>
```

Method in action class is:

```
public String test(){
at.setUrl("http://www.test.com");
 at.setLogin("ssfd");
  at.setPass("ssfd");
}
```

I am facing  the following error:

```
Info:   2017-11-29 15:23:39 ERROR Dispatcher:38 - Exception occurred during processing request: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.OgnlTextParser.evaluate(OgnlTextParser.java:22)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParseUtil.translateVariables(TextParseUtil.java:170)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParseUtil.translateVariables(TextParseUtil.java:127)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParseUtil.translateVariables(TextParseUtil.java:49)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionChainResult.execute(ActionChainResult.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371)
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: The `chain` result type is for chaining to another action. Don't use `chain`.

Comment: What should i use any exampe

Answer (score 1):

The `chain` result type doesn't redirect. Instead use `redirect` result type.

```xml
<action name="testit" class="TestAction" method="test">
        <result name = "success" type = "redirect">
            <param name="location">${at.url}</param>
            <param name="login">${at.login}</param>
            <param name="pass">${at.pass}</param>
        </result>
</action>
```